# File system mount internals

Tags: unix, filesystems, mount

What happens internally when I mount a file system on UNIX using the following command:

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /home/users
```

Please give references (articles, books etc.)

Comment: [OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29), let's start with the wikipedia page.

Comment: @kush: Not enough details...

Comment: _any_ good book on Unix internals should be sufficient, though Google should get you further ahead, and more quickly, than you might get here.

Comment: @GregA.Woods: Which book do you suggest?

Comment: _The_ classic reference is Bach's "The Design of the UNIX Operating System".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your position:  do you want to read this?  Can you read this?
http://freebsd.active-venture.com/FreeBSD-srctree/newsrc/ufs/ffs/ffs_softdep.c.html

It is McKusick's base code for the ffs file system, which is generally considered the parent of modern 
UNIX file systems.  There is no finer detail than reading source.

The reason I posted: when I taught this stuff long ago, there was a text, and then I presented example code.  Students seemed to get a lot out of it... those who actually worked on the material, to be more correct.

In this case the ffs.c code was kind of a defacto model.   So it provides a how-we-got-here-from-there.

Now all you need to do is get this:
[http://www.amazon.com/Linux-Device-Drivers-Jonathan-Corbet/dp/0596005903/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1354930353&sr=1-1&keywords=linux+drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005903)

Then ultimately download code for ext3.  And read it.